# SonarQube resolving the Internal server error

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

While running stand alone SonarQube analysis from jenkins, I'm facing the below issue

```
2016.05.25 06:31:51 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed May 25 06:31:51 -0400 2016
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  No such file or directory - /etc/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/Invalid
    org/jruby/RubyFile.java:842:in `stat'
    jar:file:/etc/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:33:in `tmpdir'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    jar:file:/etc/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:30:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/etc/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:109:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/etc/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:141:in `create'
    org/jruby/ext/tempfile/Tempfile.java:88:in `initialize'
    org/jruby/RubyIO.java:852:in `new'
```

SOnar version 5.4

Sonar runner - 2.4

Pls. advise on how to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Simon Brandhof - SonarSource : Could you pls. help me out here. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to help you without more details. For instance does this error occur on all projects or not ? Is it a regression ? Did you upgrade SonarQube recently ? Moreover the full sonar.log would help.

Comment: @Simon Brandhof : Apologies for delay in reply.Below are the details.

Comment: @Simon Brandhof : Apologies for delay in reply.Below are the details.

I'm currently running only a single project and facing this issue
No upgrade ,  installed SQ 5.4 recently .
There were no further info on the sonar.log , I have posted whats on

Comment: still sonar.log and scanner logs would help